# Obtener el total de Materia Prima en relacion a otras tablas mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener el total de MP en base a varias tablas

He intentado varias consultas pero la que mejor me ha funcionado es la que añado al final

Las tablas y sus valores son:

materia_prima

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | nombre              |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | pan hotdog          |
|  2 | salchicha p/ hotdog |
|  3 | salchicha p/ asar   |
|  4 | tocino              |
|  5 | boneless            |
|  6 | pan hamburguesa     |
|  7 | papas p/ cono       |
|  8 | carne sirloin       |
|  9 | carne hamburguesa   |
| 10 | chili               |
| 11 | queso               |
+----+---------------------+
```

ticket_producto

```
+------+-----------+-------------+
| id   | id_ticket | id_producto |
+------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 |       638 |           4 |
|    2 |       637 |          15 |
|    3 |       637 |           1 |
|    4 |       637 |           4 |
|    5 |       636 |           6 |
|    6 |       635 |          14 |
|    7 |       635 |           7 |
|    8 |       635 |           6 |
|    9 |       634 |          12 |
|   10 |       634 |           9 |
|   11 |       634 |           9 |
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

producto

```
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id | id_categoria | nombre         | id_mp           |
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1 |            2 | Sencillo       | NULL            |
|  2 |            2 | Salchi         | 3, 4            |
|  3 |            2 | Sirloin        | 8, 11           |
|  4 |            2 | Boneless       | 5               |
|  5 |            2 | Chili          | 10              |
|  6 |            3 | Sencilla       | 9, 11           |
|  7 |            3 | Tocino         | 9, 11, 4        |
|  8 |            3 | Salchi         | 9, 11, 3        |
|  9 |            3 | Sirloin        | 9,11,8          |
| 10 |            3 | Chili          | 9,11,10         |
| 11 |            3 | Doble          | 9,11,9,11       |
| 12 |            4 | Sencillas      | NULL            |
| 13 |            4 | Salchi         | 3,3             |
| 14 |            4 | Boneless       | 5,5             |
| 15 |            4 | Sirloin        | 8,8             |
| 16 |            4 | Chili          | 10,10           |
| 17 |            4 | especiales     | 7,7,3,3,5,5,8,8 |
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

categorias_producto

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| id | nombre       | id_mp   |
+----+--------------+---------+
|  1 | Todos        | NULL    |
|  2 | Dogos        | 1, 2, 4 |
|  3 | Hamburguesas | 6       |
|  4 | Papas        | 7       |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente

```
SELECT mp.id, mp.nombre, SUM(IFNULL(Cant, 0)) Cant FROM materia_prima mp
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT tp.id_ticket, tp.id_producto, MP_PROD, MP_CAT, COUNT(*) Cant FROM ticket_producto tp
            JOIN(
                SELECT p.id, p.id_categoria, p.id_mp MP_PROD, cp.id_mp MP_CAT FROM producto p 
                    JOIN categorias_producto cp ON p.id_categoria = cp.id
            ) p ON tp.id_producto = p.id
        GROUP BY 2
    ) mp ON mp.id IN (MP_PROD, MP_CAT)
GROUP BY id
```

El resultado es el siguiente

```
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | nombre              | Cant |
+----+---------------------+------+
|  1 | pan hotdog          |    3 |
|  2 | salchicha p/ hotdog |    0 |
|  3 | salchicha p/ asar   |    1 |
|  4 | tocino              |    0 |
|  5 | boneless            |    3 |
|  6 | pan hamburguesa     |    5 |
|  7 | papas p/ cono       |    3 |
|  8 | carne sirloin       |    0 |
|  9 | carne hamburguesa   |    5 |
| 10 | chili               |    0 |
| 11 | queso               |    0 |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

Falta MP de contabilizar.
Todos los que estan depues del primer "id" separado por "," en id_mp ya sea en categorias_producto o producto, pero el primer valor si lo toma en cuenta.

Espero me puedan ayudar y orientar para obtener el resultado esperado

Comment: ¿Sería posible rediseñar la tabla `categorias_producto` para que las materias primas aparecieran en diferentes filas en vez de separadas por comas? Y, ya que estamos, ¿podrías exportar a SQL las tablas para poder comprobar tu query?

Comment: TEnes problemas con el query, porque las tablas estan mal diseñadas... que es id_mp  separados por comas?

Comment: Al principio esa col im_mp era solo informativa. No pensaba en hacerlo algo con estas bases de datos pero ya tengo la app y esta en produccion. Voy a cambiar la estructura de las tablas y agregar una nueva para hacer la relacion de la MP con los productos. Igual gracias por sus comentarios